# Node reference to show only author of node

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I have create two content types as Game and Video. Now in the Video I have created 1 field type as node reference that will be referring to the Game type.

Now suppose I have 2 users as user1 and user2 on my site. User1 has created following contents-

Game1(Content Type Game) Game2(Content Type Game) Game3(Content Type Game)

And User 2 has following contents- Game4(Content Type Game) Game5(Content Type Game)

Now suppose User1 is going to create one Video content type. There on the node reference selected list I just want to see Game1,2&3. But it is displaying all Games.

How can I solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Node reference fields have a facility where you can use a View to set the list of available nodes for reference instead of selecting just a content type.

That is your best bet here.

You'll want to create a View (for this purpose) that takes an argument. That argument will be a user argument. The tricky bit will be how to set the value of that argument. You want to use the options available to set the argument even when it's not present. You might be able to set it as the logged in user, or, you might have to make a Video Creation (node form) on the users  profile page and pick the argument value based on the URL. You might also be able to set that field based on emitting links that contain the user's UID.